# SVN not showing changes

Tags: svn, rsync

Out of necessity I rsync'd the `src` folder in my SVN working directory at home with the one at work. Now when I edit files in the working directory, `svn status` doesn't think anything has been modified -- but only when I run it in the root folder. When I use it in the `src` folder, the modifications are noted by `svn status`. What did I break, how did I break it, and how can I never do it again? I don't understand SVN's underlying mechanics well enough to know why simply rsync'ing a directory would cause this issue.

**Edit 1:** Used "svn log" where I meant "svn status".

**Edit 2:** I just noticed that my root folder doesn't recognize subfolders that have been added in the past, e.g.:

```
? src
? test
? scripts
? documents
...
```

Any idea how these issues might be connected?

Comment: have you checked for .svn directories in mentioned directories?

Comment: I use synchronisation (with dropbox) with svn and no problems.

Comment: I've used dropbox, too, without issue, so I didn't think rsync would be a problem either. There indeed are .svn directories there.

Comment: Have you tried running svn cleanup?

Comment: I have. I just noticed that the root folder doesn't actually recognized any of the previously added folders, e.g., `docs`, `scripts`, etc. Maybe I've just broken the root directory somehow?